# Initialize 2d array as null in java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array, initialization

I have a question that I couldn't find its answer on the net. Does this code right?

```
double[][] F_P_F = null; 
for(int Count_Years=0; Count_Years<5;Count_Years++){ 
if( Count_Years==0){
    F_P_F=P_F.D_P(S_P_F, 1000);}
```

If the condition statement wasn't satisfied the matrix `F_P_F` matrix is modified and expanded to bigger size

The code is more complex than this but this is the general idea. I initialized `F_P_F` as null because its change its size with each time step.
My question is does't right to initialized the matrix as null and then define it as required?

Comment: Can you also post relavant section of this code:F_P_F=P_F.D_P(S_P_F, 1000);
Rest all looks fine.

Comment: Side note: `F_P_F` is a terrible variable name for Java. Java variables should be camel-case (`likeThisYouSee`) and they should be descriptive.

Comment: Note: arrays can't be null; references to arrays can be null.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't call P_F.D_P before the loop instead?

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply because I changed the whole code I discover many mistakes the idea was to define the matrix through if condition inside for loop and then use it else where in the code outside the for loop therefore I needed to define it as null out side the for loop